# Termination Condition for threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have written a multi-threaded Java application which reads a bunch of .jar files from a directory. This application spawns multiple threads and each threads reads bunch of jar files. I'm having trouble identifying the stopping condition for this application. How can i identify that all the files have been read?

The following is a snippet function which gets called from the run() method for each thread.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipException;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class ArchiveFileTest implements Runnable {
     private static boolean stopAll = false;
     private static int threadNumber = 0;
     private int myNumber = 0;

     public ArchiveFileTest () {
            myNumber = threadNumber;
            threadNumber++;
     }

     public static boolean setStopAll () {
            return setStopAll(true);
     }

     public static boolean setStopAll (boolean b) {
            stopAll = b;
            return stopAll;
     }

     public static String[] listFiles (File parentDir,final String ext1,final String ext2,final String ext3,final String ext4) {
            String allFiles[] = parentDir.list(new FilenameFilter() { 
                 public boolean accept(File pDir, String fName) {
                        if (fName.endsWith("."+ext1) || fName.endsWith("."+ext2) || fName.endsWith("."+ext3) || fName.endsWith("."+ext4)) return true;
                        else return false;
                 }
            });
            for (int i=0; i<allFiles.length; i++)
                 allFiles[i] = parentDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +  allFiles[i];
            return allFiles;
     }

     public ZipFile getMyZipFile (File parentDir) {
            String fn[] = listFiles(parentDir, "jar", "zip", "war", "rar");
            int fileNum = myNumber % fn.length;
            ZipFile zFile = null;
            for (int i=0; i<fn.length; i++) {
                 String jFile = fn[(fileNum + i)%fn.length];
                 try {
                        zFile = new ZipFile(jFile);
                        break;
                 } catch  (IOException e) {
                     setStopAll();
                 }
            }
            return zFile;
     }

     public void doStuff() throws Exception {
            File dName = new File("/home/sqatest/chander/sample-files");
          final int N_TIMES = 15;
            final int N_FILES = 500;
          int counter = 0;
            int fCount  = 0;
            if (!dName.isDirectory() || !dName.exists()) {
                 System.err.println("The parent directory given should point to an existing directory...");
                 setStopAll();
                 return;
            }
          while (counter < N_TIMES) { 
                 ZipFile zipFile = getMyZipFile(dName);
                 if (zipFile == null) {
                        System.err.println("No zip file entry for the Thread-" + myNumber);
                        break;
                 }
                 try {
                        Enumeration <? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zipFile.entries(); 
                        fCount = 0;
                        ZipEntry ze = null;
                        while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                             ze = zipEntries.nextElement();

                             if (ze.isDirectory()) continue; // if it is a directory go to next entry

                             InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(ze); 
                             fCount++;
                             int readCount = 0;
                             try {
                                    while(is.read((new byte[50])) != -1 && readCount != 200) readCount++;
                                    System.out.println("Successfully Read " + zipFile.toString());

                                    //is.close();
                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                             if (fCount == N_FILES) break;  // read maximum of N_FILES
                        }
                        if (stopAll) break;
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } finally {
                        counter++; 
                 }
          } 
     }

     public void run () {
            try {
                 doStuff();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 setStopAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }

     public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception { 
          final int MAX_THREADS = 500;
          final int MAX_HOLDING_THREADS = 5;
            int loopCount = 0;
            Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
            for (int m=0; ; m++) {
                 Thread t[] = new Thread[MAX_HOLDING_THREADS];
                 for (int n=0; n<t.length; n++) {
                        t[n] = new Thread(new ArchiveFileTest());
                        t[n].start();
                        if ((m+1)*(n+1)==MAX_THREADS) {
                             System.out.println("\n" + MAX_THREADS + " reached... \nMain Sleeping for some mins..."); 
                             loopCount++;
                             try {
                                    t[n].join();
                                    System.out.println("\nMain is back... (" + loopCount + ")");
                             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    setStopAll();
                             }
                             m = 0;
                        }
                 }
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Without the whole code, it is nigh impossible finding out what the code is doing (e.g. `setStopAll()` is not defined) and we can only guess at how the threads are created or how many files are in the directory.  N.B. each thread will read the same file 15 times unless the stopAll flag is set.

Comment: I have updated the question with entire code.

Comment: A small OT comment. Remove boolean as return type from your setters, make them return void instead as you don't use the return value and standard is void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your application will ever stop.  You've got an infinite loop in the main method:

```
for (int m=0; ; m++) {
    ....
}
```

Note, setting `m=0` inside the body won't break the loop, so I think you'll never end even if you have no file.  It then continuously reads all zip/jar/war/rar files in the directory (choosing the file based on a rotating counter `myNumber` is not very maintainable), but never exits the loop.

If you're requirement is to read ZIP files using a number of threads, then I would go about it a different way.

1. Create a Set of files which you want to look at.
2. Create a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to create a fixed pool of 5 threads
3. Iterate over the set of files and create a new `Runnable` which does the Zip Extraction (though I'm not quite sure why you read the first 10000 bytes of a ZIP entry and then don't do anything with it), and call the `execute` method.  That will use the thread pool to process 5 files at a time.
4. After submitting all the runnables Use the `shutdown` method, which will wait for all submitted tasks to finish, and the shutdown the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your class that launches the threads, have a `volatile` counter for your running threads.
2. In your thread constructor pass a reference to the launching class.
3. Have a synchronized method to let the threads notify the launching class that they are done.
4. After instancing and starting your threads wait for the counter to become 0;

   ```
   while(getRunningThreads() > 0) // getRunningThreads must be synchronized too
       Thread.sleep(500); // Check every half second.
   ```

Comment: Also don't forget to make counter field `volatile`

Comment: it's better to make counter `AtomicInteger` because otherwise, it's value will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

If by stopping you mean terminating then the application will stop when all threads, that are not daemon special case, are finished.

Comment: But that wont guarantee that all the archive files have been read. What i want to achieve is to stop when all the files have been read.

Comment: I have only glanced at your code but conceptually you shouldn't have to use any stop method, boolean or whatever to stop your program, it should stop it self and probably already do? when all files are read.

Comment: Nope, it doesnt stop. I tried with just one file in the folder and it kept on reading it. I had to Ctrl + C it to stop it